# Ошибка при попытке использования random с файлом

Tags: python

есть 2 файла, один со списком (l1st.txt), в другой нужно вывести результат(result.txt).

```py
import random

with open("result.txt") as chance:
    with open("l1st.txt") as chance_2:
        parameter = random.choice(chance_2)
    chance.write("Результат ",parameter)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```py
  File "/home/artem/Рабочий стол/Python/dbd.py", line 6, in <module>
    parameter = random.choice(chance_2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 258, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

Что нужно изменить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
parameter = random.choice(chance_2)
```

на

```
parameter = random.choice(chance_2.readlines())
```

т.к. chance_2 у вас - объект файла. По самому этому объекту программа ничего не знает о его содержимом, сначала надо это содержимое прочитать из этого файла.

Ну и про запись в соседнем комментарии верно сказали, но это уже другая ошибка, до неё ваш код даже не доходит, так как спотыкается ещё до этого.

Answer (score 0):

1)Вы в chance пытаетесь записать, но туда нельзя записать, там только чтение

> измените на

`with open("result.txt",'w') as chance:`

2) файлы в (студию) скиньте на файловый хостинг

Answer (score 0):

[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) умеет работать только с объектами для которых определен метод `len` и обращение к элементам по целочисленному индексу (метод `__getitem__`), т.е. с последовательностями ([sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) - "An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a `__len__()` method that returns the length of the sequence.")
Такие ограничения нужны, чтобы сгенерировать случайный индекс от `0` до `len()-1`, вернуть элемент по этому индексу. Примеры таких типов: `list`, `str`, `tuple`, `bytes`.

У файла нет метода `len` (о чем прямо написано в ошибке) и нет доступа по индексу. Зато эти методы есть у списков. Простое решение - преобразовать объект файла к списку (файл - итерируемый объект, его можно преобразовать в список):

```
with open("l1st.txt") as chance_2:
    parameter = random.choice(list(chance_2))
```

Или другой вариант:

```
with open("l1st.txt") as chance_2:
    parameter = random.choice(chance_2.readlines())
```

Результат тот же самый - метод `readlines()` возвращает все строки в файле списком, из которого уже выбирается произвольная строка.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("l1st.txt") as chance_2, open('result.txt', 'w')as chance:
    chance.write(random.choice([ ''.join(line.split()) for line in chance_2 ]))
```

---

l1st.txt

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
```